# Brackets and comma usage

Tags: punctuation, commas, parentheses, parenthetical-commas

In the following sentence

> Check out our newly created (by people) directory for quick and easy to access information.

should I be using a comma after the closing bracket and after the word *quick*? Or should there be any commas used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, brackets parenthesise text such that the sentence should read just the same, i.e. grammatically complete, with the parenthesised section removed. Remove that section from your example and the comma left behind would be incorrect.

I might suggest altering the sentence structure such that brackets are not required though, e.g.,

> Check out our new directory, created by people, for quick and easy access to information.

or this

> Check out our new, people-created directory, for quick and easy access to information.

Comment: Cool. Thanks Toby, especially for the suggestion ;-)